# DocuSign API Carbon Copy

Tags: docusignapi

Currently using the DocuSign API, I have a signer and an email to cc the completed documents to. Is it possible to send the completed documents to the docusign account of the (cc person)? For example, if I'm being cc'd the emails, I want my docusign account which is registered with the same email to be able to view my documents on the website. Can the API achieve this? I have already completed the part where the signer and the cc receives emails so for the most part everything is already working.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the cc person has a DocuSign account, then they should be able to see the envelopes with their documents in it for envelopes they were cc'd on.

You can try this in the developer sandbox by adding a second user to your account. You can make the second user an admin or not.

Answer (score 0):

I would second Larry's response, but point out that it's not enough for the email address to match exactly, but the full name must also match exactly what's in the DocuSign account. Otherwise - it will not be tied to the other account for this person.